# suggestion needed for changing the front end

Tags: java, vaadin

i have done and web site with php and it gets the datas from an db in tokyo cabinate with java... and i am planning to change the front end php with java (vaadin)UI and i need to know will it be fast like php and can designing can be done easily .... how efficient the vaadin is compared to php is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will it be fast like php

I think that probably depends on how you use it and what you mean by "fast".  Certainly, Vaadin involves a lot of extra stuff that needs to be downloaded to the user's browser the first time the user visits your site.  But the flip-side is that that stuff results in a really nice user interface.  Vaadin can also offload a lot of the UI interactions to the user's browser, potentially reducing server load and making your site more responsive after the first visit.

Your site's business logic and back-end will be implemented in Java, and should in theory be faster than PHP.  However, that will depend on you getting the design and implementation right.  If you have not used Java before, you are likely to make a few performance-related mistakes along the way.

But this is all generalities.  You probably should try some experiments.